# what is a good data structure to store a permutation and how many times that permutation occurs?

Tags: c++, sorting, data-structures, containers, permutation

my permutations are unique pairs of numbers. I need to go through a list and count the number of times a given permutation occurs. So i need to record it in a data structure.

```
(1,1) 0
(1,2) 5
(1,3) 3
(2,2) 5
(2,3) 2
(3,3) 1
```

Ultimately, I need to be able to sort this container in the decreasing order so I can get the permutations which occurs the maximum number of times.
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Are the pairs stored within a std::pair objects?

Comment: What?  A permutation occurs once, else its not a permutation.

Comment: This is a *near* duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10200806/179910, and my answer to that question applies here as well, with a minor adjustment if the key type from `int` to `std::pair<int, int>`.

Comment: @ZakariaSoliman no im not sure what i can put them in...maybe a map?

Comment: If you only need the "greatest" element of a set, then a full sort of the entire container is not necessary.  A single bubble sort pass will either put the greatest or the least at the end or start (depending on which direction you traverse and which comparison you swap on) in only O(n) time, rather than a full sort which will most likely be no faster than O(n lg n).  You don't even need to actually swap, just scan the container keeping track of the location of the "greatest" element seen yet, a faster O(n) operation by avoiding unnecessary swapping.

Comment: that's transpositions perhaps, but general permutations usually have much more elements...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int>`. Insert like this:

```
std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int> myMap;
typedef std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int>::iterator Iterator;
// Insert "permutation" (0,1) with a default of 0 uses
Iterator it=myMap.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_pair(0, 1), 0)).first;
++it->second; // Increment use count - will use old count if already there
```

You don't even need to sort it afterwards, you can always just record the current maximum after each insertion!

Note that the outer pair in the insert carries a default value for your number of uses. This will be set to 0 if the element is not already in the map. So in case the permutation already exists, it will find you the map element, otherwise it will insert it and set the use count to zero. Then you just increment it either way!

Comment: If you are using a C++11 compiler, you can use `auto` instead of the **typedef** :)

Comment: Yea, and you'd use an unordered map instead of a map. Just figured I'd stick with C++03 since this is not tagged C++11

Comment: @Itjax this is what I was thinking but I'm not sure if it will work for a large dataset? Also, I do need to sort it in a descending order as it is a requirement so wouldn't that be a problem?

Comment: @sumrania, If you need it sorted, you should probably copy it into a vector and sort that or insert into an "inverted" multi-map after you are done counting. You can also use an unordered_map instead of the map - it'll probably be faster, but use the same amount of memory

Comment: Why would you use an unordered map per se? You'd check its performance first by profiling, I would hope.

Answer (score 0):

I would just make an unordered map of pair to int (assuming int is sufficient, you might need a long or an arbitrarily big integer). Just increment the value if the key already exists, otherwise set the value to 1